# Xcode 6 Adding tableHeaderView in IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

In Xcode 5 I was able to drag a `UIView` into a `UITableView` in IB to create the header. However in Xcode 6, IB won't let me drop one inside. Is there no way to create the table header in IB anymore?

Comment: Yeah Xcode 6 sucks but after 6-7 attempts I was able to achieve it.

Answer (score 37):

You just drag a `UIView` to the top of the table (above the "Prototype cells" text) and hold it there. The drop indicator changes to a single horizontal line with a small circle at either end. When you drop it, it makes a header.

You can do similar at the bottom to make a footer.

For a table view controller in a storyboard:

[image]

For a table view in a xib:

[image]

Comment: It's more trickier with Xcode 6 than before. Took me 10 minutes and countless tries to achieve it

Comment: Seriously? I'm holding it on top of the Table and it never lets me drop it inside. I figured out a hack which worked for me, posting as answer below

Comment: You need to hold it above the "prototype cells" text. The drop indicator changes to a blue line with circles to the left and right of the table. I'll try and get a screen recording of it.

Comment: Ya maybe a screenshot can help. I don't see a "prototype cells" view anywhere in IB or anywhere else I can drop a UIView on top of

Comment: Are you in a storyboard, or a xib?

Comment: Screen recordings added, for both options

Comment: I'm using a nib. I was trying to drop it in place inside the Document Outline like I've done in Xcode 5 but I guess that no longer works. This is much trickier to get working, I'm glad I had a Header already setup in Xcode 5 that I was able to copy/paste into my new nibs.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I ended up modifying the xml of the xib manually in order to drop in a footer (I didn't previously have one in a different xib to copy over). I'm doing the exact same thing you are but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: I think the table view needs to be a top-level view. I could not get this to work when embedded in container view.

Answer (score 5):

Right click the XIB file and select 'Open As' , select Source Code

Look for the tableview XML Element and replace with the following

```
  <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" showsHorizontalScrollIndicator="NO" showsVerticalScrollIndicator="NO" style="plain" separatorStyle="none" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="YCz-1P-cVv">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <view key="tableHeaderView" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="vv3-pk-N2N">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="156"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" id="yho-bJ-IzF">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="25" width="320" height="44"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                        </imageView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
            </tableView>
```

Save and open the XIB with the Interface Builder XIB Document.

Comment: Yup this is what I ended up doing. Manually editing the xml was the only way I could add a header or footer into my table without copying from an existing table.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should add table header and footer view by source code.
first right click on IB and open as source code, then put below code

```
<tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" style="plain" separatorStyle="none" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="MZF-la-Fpw">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                <view key="tableHeaderView" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="IDM-OR-d2g">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="40"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <view key="tableFooterView" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Q4z-o4-2rB">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="518" width="320" height="50"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="dataSource" destination="-1" id="guW-ch-dgt"/>
                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="-1" id="j1u-5q-dsq"/>
                </connections>
            </tableView>
```

Answer (score -1):

What I ended up doing (which worked great) was to copy an already existing `UITableView` with a header from another NIB I had previously setup with Xcode 5. Then I simply deleted everything else from that Table except the header just so I could get it setup properly. However this trick will only work if you've setup a Table with a Header in Xcode 5 before. If you're working with a new Xcode 6 project I still don't have a solution.